# Include equal or greater than correctly sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add an equal or greater than 20.0 parameter in this sql statement called from a JSP template, however it's giving me sql syntax error all the time near the HAVING sum(amount):

```
 "SELECT performId,sum(amount) AS totalAmount FROM performTransactions"+ 
 " WHERE  time >= STR_TO_DATE('" + (ftd.format(timeFrom)) + "', '%Y.%m.%d %H:%i:%s')" + 
 " AND time < STR_TO_DATE('" + (ftd.format(timeTo)) + "', '%Y.%m.%d %H:%i:%s')" + 
 " AND type IN (1, 2)  GROUP BY performId ORDER BY totalAmount DESC" + 
 " HAVING sum(amount) >= 20.0" ;
```

I tried to include the parameter in a different position, but it was sending "invalid use of group function", how can I set correctly sum(amount) or totalAmount greater than 20.0 correctly?
Thank you

Comment: Just formatting the above I see that having needs to have a space in front otherwise it's DESCHaving. instead of DESC Having  so either add `DESC "` or `" HAVING...`

Comment: group by - having should be together and order by after that.

Comment: Hi Abhik, I don't know if HAVING is correct, I think it is as for some answers I saw, what I need to know is how to include sum(amount) equal or greater than 20.0 in that sql, is HAVING correct? or should I write AND sum(amount) >= 20.0 ?

Comment: You could use `HAVING totalAmount  >= 20` , but it should be before the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HAVING comes before ORDER BY:

```
"SELECT performId,sum(amount) AS totalAmount FROM performTransactions"+ 
 " WHERE  time >= STR_TO_DATE('" + (ftd.format(timeFrom)) + "', '%Y.%m.%d %H:%i:%s')" + 
 " AND time < STR_TO_DATE('" + (ftd.format(timeTo)) + "', '%Y.%m.%d %H:%i:%s')" + 
 " AND type IN (1, 2)  GROUP BY performId " + 
 " HAVING sum(amount) >= 20.0" 
 " ORDER BY totalAmount DESC";
```